# Connecting to TFS2012 from Win2003 SP2

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-server-2003, msscci

Anyone who knows how to connect to TFS2012 from an image running Win2003R2 64bit SP2 and VS2005?

Looking at the "Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 MSSCCI Provider 64-bit" provider, it states that the Win2003SP1 should be supported, but I'm getting the error:

"Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Team Explorer or its tool are not  registered. Please install or repair your Team Foundation Client Installation".

I didn't succeed in installing the VS2012 Team Explorer because it does not support the OS.

Any hints?

Best regards
Morten

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Wrong Post! sorry... I intended to write somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to answer my own question the solution is to install:

1. [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=329)
2. [TFS 2010 MSSCCI provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6)

From within VS2005 add source control (File->Source Control). It will launch a VS2010 shell where you can configure the connection to TFS2012. Pretty straight forward.

Beware that you can only use source control functionality (check in/out).

HTH
Morten